# Can't loop through $form_state->setErrorByName?

Tags: forms, 8

I want to display an error message if the form field is empty.

```
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $entry = array(
        'name' => $form_state->getValue('name'),
        'lastname' => $form_state->getValue('lastname'),
        'cardnumber' => $form_state->getValue('cardnumber'),
        'month' => $form_state->getValue('month'),
        'year' => $form_state->getValue('year'),
        'cvv' => $form_state->getValue('cvv'),    
    );
    foreach ($entry as $key => $value) {
     if (empty($value)) { 

      $form_state->setErrorByName($key, $this->t('cannot be empty.'));

        } 
     }
  }
```

but I only get:

> cannot be empty.

If I use instead:

```
foreach ($entry as $key => $value) {
  if (empty($value)) { 

    drupal_set_message(t('<b>%key</b> cannot be empty.', ['%key' => $key]), 'error');

    } 
}
```

Results how I want it:

> **name** cannot be empty.
>
> **lastname** cannot be empty.
>
> **cardnumber** cannot be empty.
>
> **month** cannot be empty.
>
> **year** cannot be empty.
>
> **cvv** cannot be empty.

Except the problem here is that the form input box does not become highlighted in red.

**How can I make it loop through the first method? or is it like that by design?**

Comment: did you tried with $form_state->setErrorByName($key=>value, $this->t('cannot be empty.'));??

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this yourself instead of using `['#required']`?

Comment: @googletorp ugh.. I wasn't aware of that, thx. I will use this instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you simply need to replace:

```
$form_state->setErrorByName($key, $this->t('cannot be empty.'));
```

with

```
$form_state->setErrorByName($key, $this->t('<b>%key</b> cannot be empty.', ['%key' => $key]));
```

According to the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AsetErrorByName/8), the first parameter will identify the field and the second will be the message to output.

In your code, the $message string is outputed as expected, you need to prefix it with the $key parameter, the same way you do with `drupal_set_message`.

Comment: edited your answer, as when using your original answer it filtered the `<b> tags` as potential harmful code and was displaying them literally on the message. Ex: `<b>Name</b> cannot be empty`